# Image of linear transformation.

Tags: linear-algebra

If the span of vector $x$ is the image of the linear transformation $\alpha$, does it means that $x$ is also an image of the corresponding matrix of $\alpha$, let's call that matrix $A$. Basically, what I am trying to figure out is the relation between the image of linear operator and image of a matrix of that linear operator. Are they the same? If they are, why? If not, then why not?

So is it true that if $$\operatorname{Image}(\alpha)=\operatorname{span}(x) \Leftrightarrow \operatorname{Image}(A)=\operatorname{span}(x)$$ where $A$ is the matrix of the operator $\alpha$?

Comment: $\alpha(x)$ can be written as $Ax$.

Comment: @Koto And what it actually means

Comment: @Koto - Only if $x$ is represented in a basis compatible with the matrix representation.

Comment: @cdummie -- Your confusion stems from the fact that you write "the matrix" of the operator $\alpha$. In general there are many matrices representing the same operator. Your confusion will go away once you convince yourself that a matrix is only a representation of an operator, and that this representation depends on a choice of coordinates, i.e, a basis.

Comment: @uniquesolution I know, there is more than one matrix (in general) that can represent the operator, matrix representation of operator is not unique, it all depends on which basis i choose, just like you stated, but i knew that already, just like i knew the expression $\alpha(x)=Ax$ i just don't know how those things can help me to determine is my statement true or false?

Comment: @cdummie I can only infer about what you know by what you write, and there are still non-trivial discrepancies, if I may say so.

Comment: @uniquesolution ofcourse you can, after all, i am the one looking for help here, however, problem still remains, i mean, image of linear operator is set of all elements of codomain we get after we map elements of the domain, then, image of matrix is image of operator $\alpha$ if it's defined as $Ax$ where $x$ is argument,  and i am having trouble understanding relation between these two things.